# Command Link in .NET4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, clr

Is it possible to create a "Command Link" button in Visual C++ (CLR/Windows Forms Application)?

I'm really happy it is described so well in the "Design Guidelines", but there isn't any code sample, nor a reference anywhere.

If you're not sure what I'm talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511455.aspx

Sorry if it's explained somewhere (how to use it/if it's deprecated), but my searching keeps yielding results about ASP.NET or "Command Line"...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3121022/60761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this article helpful:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/03/12/command_5f00_link.aspx

The summary is that a command link is *not* a separate control. It's just a normal button control with two specific styles applied. You can make your own with code similar to this (original example is C# rather than C++/CLR):

```
public class CommandLink:Button
{
    const int BS_COMMANDLINK = 0x0000000E;

    public CommandLink()
    {
        this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    }


    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cParams = base.CreateParams;
            cParams.Style |= BS_COMMANDLINK;
            return cParams;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think i saw that somewhere... the problem is I've got the app in CLR and can't find a way to style the button... even if there is the "button->setStyle()" method, there isn't a constant for Command Link style...

Comment: @Set - updated my answer a bit -- the code now includes the required constant.